# Unable to connect on the local network to ASP.NET Core swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

> Unable to connect on the local network to asp.net web API

I run it through *Kestrel* and access is available only through the computer on which the launch occurred, everything broke at the time of the attempt to publish to *docker*, before that it **worked fine**, so I decided to remove its support and everything broke. How can I fix local access, please tell me?

I wanted to try to run a docker inside the container, in the end nothing happened on the linux VM, then running in VS I noticed that access to the local network was gone, I deleted the docker from the project and the problem was not solved, it was not solved even after deleting the docker profile in `launchSettings.json` .many will write that you need to run through kestrel and everything will work, I repeat, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that I changed the db connection string in the process. Since my colleagues, like me, have a clone of the same system, one of the ip addresses was the same for everyone and I specified it, in connection with which the program tried to log into the local database on the device for all those who connected

Comment: Can you add a solution to the answer? For example, did everyone change the hardcoded IP?

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to access your ASP.NET Web API on your local network when running it through Kestrel and the issue occurred after trying to publish to Docker, it's possible that the Docker settings or network configurations have affected your local access. To fix local network access, you can follow these steps:

Check Docker Network Configuration:

Ensure that Docker is not interfering with your local network configuration. Docker may create its own network bridge that can sometimes disrupt your local network. Verify Docker's network settings and try to reconfigure them if needed.
Check IP Binding:

Make sure that your ASP.NET Web API is configured to bind to the correct IP address and port. You can specify the IP address to bind in your Startup.cs or Program.cs file. Use UseUrls method to specify the IP address and port. For example:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000");  // Listen on all available network interfaces
```

Firewall and Antivirus:

Check your firewall and antivirus software settings to ensure they are not blocking network access to your ASP.NET Web API.
Network Profile:

Ensure that your local network is set to a "Private" or "Home" network profile in your operating system settings. This will typically allow your application to be accessed on the local network.
Check Docker Containers:

If you were running Docker containers, make sure there are no conflicting containers using the same ports. Docker containers can bind to ports and prevent other services from using them.
Rebuild Your Project:

Sometimes, issues like this can be resolved by rebuilding your project and making sure all dependencies are properly restored.
IP Address and Hostname Resolution:

Check that the IP address and hostname of the machine where your ASP.NET Web API is running are correctly resolved within your local network. DNS or host file entries may be required for proper resolution.
Access Restrictions:

Ensure that there are no access restrictions or rules in your project or server-side code that may limit access to specific IP addresses or interfaces.
Docker Cleanup:

Even after removing Docker support, some Docker-related settings or configurations may persist. You can try a cleanup process, which might include removing any remnants of Docker configurations.
Hosts File:

Check the hosts file on your local machine to see if there are any custom host entries that might affect network access. The hosts file is typically located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows.
Router Configuration:

Ensure that your router or network infrastructure isn't blocking access to your local machine.
Network Stack Configuration:

Check if any changes were made to the network stack configuration on your machine that might affect network access.
If you've tried these steps and still face issues, it's possible that the Docker-related changes left some residual configurations. You may want to consider a clean reinstallation of Docker if it's no longer needed for your project. Additionally, consulting with your organization's IT department or network administrator for assistance may be beneficial if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work, the method you suggested would probably work, but in the current VS realities it doesn't even start because of the spelling change. I guess I'll have to start over anyway and not do anything stupid this time.